# Number of element in a list in lambd-calculus?

Tags: coq, lambda-calculus

I am coding polymorphe lists in coq and I have defined the type as

```
Definition listA A :Set :=
    forall T :Set, T -> (A -> T -> T) -> T.
(* empty list*)
Definition pnil (A :Set) : listA A := 
      fun T: Set => fun (x : T ) => fun (c : A -> T -> T) => x.
     
Definition pcons (A :Set): A -> (listA A) -> (listA A):=
    fun (a : A) (q : listA A) => fun T : Set => fun (x : T ) => fun (c : A -> T -> T) => c a (q T x c).
```

but when I try to count how many element are in a list I get an error:

```
Unknown constructor: pcons.
```

this is the code I wrote for counting the elements.

```
Fixpoint nb_elements (A :Set ) (l :listA A): nat :=
    match l with 
        | pnil => 0
        |pcons A e t => 1 + (nb_elements A t)
    end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `listA` is the encoding of lists in *System F*, the polymorphic lambda calculus. To work with these lists, you need to use them as functions rather than resorting to Coq's `match` statement. For example:

```
Definition nb_elements (A : Set) (l : listA A) : nat :=
  l nat 0 (fun (x : A) (count : nat) => S count).
```

Intuitively, the second argument of a `listA` specifies what to return on the base case, whereas the third argument specifies what to do with a non-empty list. Here, if the list is empty, the number of elements is 0. If the list is non-empty, suppose that we have already computed the number of elements of its tail, which we'll call `count`. Then, to compute the number of elements of the entire list, we just need to add one to `count`.

In practice, it is very rare to work with encoded data types such as `listA` in Coq. Usually, we use inductively defined types, which allow us to work with `match` statements. Here is a version of your example using an inductive list type:

```
Inductive list A : Set :=
| nil : list A
| cons : A -> list A -> list A.
Arguments nil {A}.
Arguments cons {A}.

Fixpoint nb_elements (A : Set) (l : list A) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 0
  | cons x l' => S (nb_elements A l')
  end.
```